# Python ValueError when using local function in map

Tags: python, function, namespaces

I'm trying to make a list containing data which has been processed by different functions. The below code does not work, because the two functions a and b are not within the scope of the map function

```
def outer_func():
    def a():
        return "Something"
    def b():
        return "Something else"
    map(lambda x: eval(x)(), ['a', 'b'])
```

I tried wrapping the functions in a class, and the below code works just fine.

```
class fcontainer():
    def a(self):
        return "Something"

    def b(self):
        return "Something else"

def test():
    f = fcontainer()
    return map(lambda x: getattr(f, x)(), ['a', 'b'])
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Why do a and b not exist within the map function?
2. Is there a 'right' way to do what I'm trying to do?
3. Should I finally sit down and wrap my head around decorators? :)

Thank you!

UPDATE: The first example can be made to work by first fetching the functions while within the scope of outer_func, and then using map:

```
functions = [eval(i) for i in ['a', 'b']]
return map(lambda x: x(), functions)
```

This works, but it's two lines instead of one >:|

Answer (score 4):

Is it necessary to have a list of strings (`['a', 'b']`)? Maybe you'd better put the function objects directly into the list: `[a, b]`.

```
return map(lambda x: x(), [a, b])
```

seems quite easy to me.

If you want to do it as decorators, it won't be much easier:

```
def outer_func():
    funcs = []
    def funcapp(func): # so that a and b are still in place...
        funcs.append(func)
        return func
    @funcapp
    def a():
        return "Something"
    @funcapp
    def b():
        return "Something else"
    return funcs
```

Comment: Why bother with your own class? `@myList.append`

Comment: @Eric Sometimes we tend to oversee the simplest things. Thank you.

Comment: Having said that, using `@myList.append` results in `a` being `None`, but in this case that doesn't matter

Comment: @Eric Right, that's why it is ok to make this change.

Comment: Thank you for a very instructive answer! return map(lambda x: x(), [a, b]) does indeed do the trick, and it's nice and clean! I guess mine was another case of overlooking the simplest things :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `eval` executes in the right context, by giving it the `globals` and `locals` inside `outer_func()`.

```
def outer_func():
    def a():
        return "Something"
    def b():
        return "Something else"
    map(lambda x, g=globals(), l=locals(): eval(x, g, l)(), ['a', 'b'])
```

Having said that, `eval` is probably not the solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I never understood the point of having to supply locals as an argument to eval before now.

Answer (score 0):

In python, we have a special feature where you can pass a function just like a variable.

Your first approach is almost correct,.. slightly missed :)

```
>>> def outer_func():
...     def a():
...         return "Something"
...     def b():
...         return "Something else"
...     print map(lambda x: x(), [a, b])
...
>>> outer_func()
['Something', 'Something else']
```

eval is really good but like you faced, it has a risk of

If use this for your second approach, it will work.

```
>>> def test():
...     f = fcontainer()
...     return map(lambda x: x(), [f.a, f.b])
...
>>> test()
['Something', 'Something else']
```

Now, to your questions :

**Q1. Why do a and b not exist within the map function?**

MAP function is special. It does nt bother what is outside its scope. This makes it much more faster. check below code to understand.

```
>>> dir() # used to check local variables/function defined already.
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'outer_func']
>>> map( lambda x: dir() , range(5))
[['x'], ['x'], ['x'], ['x'], ['x']]
>>> # as you can see within MAP, outer_func is missing.
```

**Q2. Is there a 'right' way to do what I'm trying to do?**

There is a easier way to do it :)

**Q3. Should I finally sit down and wrap my head around decorators?**

I think you already got answer by now. So for now no decorations

Hope this helps you :)